# CRM 4 codename field on Campaign entity - can't update value

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to update value of codename field on Campaign entity but it wont let me do. 
In C# code if I debug, I can see it goes through without any error and saves everything else except codename value.

On CRM form it is read only field and if I try to amend it and change value from 12345 to 12345678 for example it does not save.

Any idea what might be preventing it? When I create a new record I can add any value I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observations are correct: `codename` on Campaign can be set when creating a record but cannot be updated.

This information can be seen in the CRM SDK.

See [`campaign.codename` in the CRM 4.0 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151912.aspx):

- Valid for create:    Yes
- Valid for retrieve:   Yes
- Valid for update:    No

Comment: Thanks Henrik, it helped